# Nested For loop not working when looped 8 times

Tags: c++

When i did a nested for loop 4 times like this,

```
int time[257] = {};

for(int i1 = 1; i1 < 65; i1++)
    for(int i2 = 1; i2 < 65; i2++)
        for (int i3 = 1; i3 < 65; i3++)
            for (int i4 = 1; i4 < 65; i4++) 
                time[i1 + i2 + i3 + i4]++;
```

Its able to output properly.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 257; i++) {
    cout << time[i] << endl;
}
```

However, when i increase the nested for loop to 8 times, there isn't any output.

```
for (int i1 = 1; i1 < 66; i1++)
    for (int i2 = 1; i2 < 66; i2++)
        for (int i3 = 1; i3 < 66; i3++)
            for (int i4 = 1; i4 < 66; i4++)
                for (int i5 = 1; i5 < 66; i5++)
                    for (int i6 = 1; i6 < 66; i6++)
                        for (int i7 = 1; i7 < 66; i7++)
                            for (int i8 = 1; i8 < 66; i8++)
                                    time[i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + i5 + i6 + i7 + i8]++;
```

I have tested the loop using cout. Seems like the loop just stucks at the first level.
Second time posting here, have tried looking at possible duplicate post. If i violate any of the rules and regulations here, i will remove this post.

Comment: it still in progress... here 66^8 = 360040606269696 iterations

Comment: Please show us a [mcve].  In particular, show us the declaration of `time`  (at the end of the innermost loop, you will modify `time[520]`).

Comment: @Kozyr Thats what i suspected, when i cout at the last loop the time[i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + i5 + i6 + i7 + i8] it just keeps printing the numbers non-stop. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: As @Kozyr said it's large number of iterations actually 65^8, on speed  equals 1Ghz per iteration you will iterate 3.5 days ( (65^8) / 1000000000 / 3600 / 24 ).

Comment: @Logman Even adding one more loop (5 total) would not make it work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute force is a very bad idea to solve it. You have to use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)  approach: calculate next state `n+1` from state `n`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int N = 8;
    std::map<int, long long> W;
    for (int k = 1; k < 66; ++k) W[k] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
        std::map<int, long long> Q;
        for (auto const& w : W) {
            for (int k = 1; k < 66; ++k) {
                Q[w.first + k] += w.second;
            }
        }
        swap(Q, W);
    }

    for (auto const& w: W) {
        cout << w.first << ": " << w.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The output is exactly what i wanted. But there is some part to this code which i don't understand. "for (auto const& w : W)" what does the w:W do?

Comment: @jonathanhojh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for_loop You need a more up to date book!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The array `time[257]` can have 257 elements at the most.
But `time[i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + i5 + i6 + i7 + i8]` means index can go upto `8 * 65 = 520`, which exceeds the limit resulting in an out-of-bounds memory access.

This will lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

> undefined behavior - **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**. Examples of undefined behavior **are memory accesses outside of array bounds**, signed integer overflow, null pointer dereference, modification of the same scalar more than once in an expression without sequence points, access to an object through a pointer of a different type, etc. Compilers are not required to diagnose undefined behavior (although many simple situations are diagnosed), and the compiled program is not required to do anything meaningful.

Comment: Tried increasing the array size to 520. But the output is still the same.

Comment: Array Size should be at least 521 as index starts from 0

Comment: I've tried up to 999, could it be that the for loop is too long or it just never exit the loop at all?

Comment: @jonathanhojh Yes, it's probably taking a very long time. Try with 5, 6 and 7 loops and see how the time grows.

Comment: @jonathanhojh:  Yes, that is a possibility. You can split the for loops into two groups and Use the computation from the first group in the second.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I've tried that too, anything more than 4 loops it would just not output anything.

Comment: @P.W yes i tried that. But the desired output is not what i was looking for. If i did 4 loops the first 3 number outputted would be zeros. What i need to output would be 7 zeros instead.

Comment: @jonathanhojh How long does it take for 4 loops? How long did you wait for 5 loops? If it took 10 seconds for 4 loops then it will take at least 10 minutes for 5, but it could be much worse (cache effects).

Comment: @MaxLanghof That explains why! It took around 6-7 seconds.